# Group related list using linq

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, grouping

I need to know what would be the best way to achieve the mentioned result:

I have below class:

```
public class Log
{
    public HashSet<string> Ids { get; set; }
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
}
public class GroupModel 
{
    public List<Log> Logs { get; set; }
}
```

And Data set like below:

```
GroupModel webApiGroupModel = new GroupModel()
        {
            Logs = new List<Log>()
            {
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){"a","g"},
                    UniqueId = "1"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){"b", "c" },
                    UniqueId = "2"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){"a", "b"},
                    UniqueId = "3"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){"e"},
                    UniqueId = "4"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){ "d", "e" },
                    UniqueId = "5"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){ "f"},
                    UniqueId = "6"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){ "g"},
                    UniqueId = "7"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){ "a", "g" },
                    UniqueId = "8"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){ "h", "e","g" },
                    UniqueId = "9"

                },
                new Log()
                {
                    Ids = new HashSet<string>(){ },//Intentionally left blank
                    UniqueId = "10"

                },
            }
        };
```

I need to group them based on related Ids, **so the result will be like below**:

Group1 = list with UniqueId 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9

Group2 = list with uniqueId 6

Group3 = list with Unique Id 10

**Explanation:**

Group1: If any Log match with any Ids item they must be grouped in one. As Log with uniqueId 1 has Ids "a,g" which are present in Log with Unique id 3,7,8,9 so these are gouped however 3,7,8,9 other items too i.e "b,e" which are present in 2 , 4, 5 so all of these are grouped i.e 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9

Group2,3 Ids are not present in any Log so they are in unique group.

I am trying to achieve this in a best way possible as the solution which i used takes 2 minute to group data set with 25K logs which is very bad.
The maximum possible Ids in each Log can be 3.

Below is the my solution, you can help me in optimizing this or provide a completely different approach to achieve the mentioned result.

```
private static ICollection<List<Log>> GroupIds(List<Log> logs)
    {
        Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> tempgroupedIds = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>();
        HashSet<string> UniqueIds = new HashSet<string>();
        HashSet<string> tempgroupedIds2 = new HashSet<string>();
        int id = 1;

        foreach (var log in logs)
        {
            List<int> tempGroupNames = new List<int>();
            foreach (var Id in log.Ids)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
                {
                    UniqueIds = new HashSet<string>(logs
                        .Where(d => d.Ids.Contains(Id)).Select(p => p.UniqueId));

                    var OtherLogsContainingUniqueIds = tempgroupedIds
                        .Where(d => UniqueIds != null && d.Value.Intersect(UniqueIds).Any())
                        .Select(d => d.Key);
                    if (OtherLogsContainingUniqueIds.Any())
                    {
                        tempGroupNames.AddRange(OtherLogsContainingUniqueIds.ToList());
                    }
                }

                if (tempGroupNames.Any())
                {
                    var tempCorelationids = new HashSet<string>(tempgroupedIds.Where(d => tempGroupNames.Contains(d.Key)).SelectMany(a => a.Value));
                    tempCorelationids.UnionWith(UniqueIds);

                    foreach (var groupname in tempGroupNames)
                    {
                        //If id is found in exiting group put all the Ids from this group to the existing group and remove this group
                        tempgroupedIds.Remove(groupname);
                    }

                    tempgroupedIds2.UnionWith(UniqueIds);
                    tempgroupedIds.Add(id, tempCorelationids);
                    id++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // This a unique group untill some other log is found containing this Id
                    tempgroupedIds2.UnionWith(UniqueIds);
                    tempgroupedIds
                        .Add(id, UniqueIds);
                    id++;
                }
            }
        }

        ICollection<List<Log>> finalGroup = new Collection<List<Log>>();

        foreach (var groupedlogKey in tempgroupedIds)
        {
            var group = logs
                .Where(a => groupedlogKey.Value.Contains(a.UniqueId)).ToList();
            finalGroup.Add(group);
        }

        //With empty Ids
        var anonymousLogs = logs
            .Where(a => !tempgroupedIds2.Contains(a.UniqueId)).ToList();
        if (anonymousLogs.Count >= 1)
        {
            finalGroup.Add(anonymousLogs);
        }

        return finalGroup;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will be better if you can update the question with code you have tried

Comment: Yeah whats your solution so far so we know not to give you the same one

Comment: Also how are we going to compare speed if we dont know what you ahve

Comment: Sure, I updated the question with my solution.

Comment: If you have a working solution but want some improvements (performance, code style, architecture etc), then it's better to ask a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm contains many inner linear operations on the input list, which make it quadratic `O(N*N*K)` time complexity (with `K` being bug enough to additionally affect the performance).

The time critical part is determining the unique sets of correlated ids by merging each element ids with each intersecting element ids.

In order to do that efficiently, we will use single pass to build a structure like this

```
var idSetById = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
```

where the following constraints hold:

```
foreach (var item in idSetById)
{
     Debug.Assert(item.Value.Contains(item.Key));
     foreach (var id in item.Value)
         Debug.Assert(idSetById.ContainsKey(id) && idSetById[id] == idSet);
}
```

Why? First because it can be created in linear time, and second, the above constraints allow it to be used as efficient `GroupBy` key selector

```
.GroupBy(log => idSetById[log.Ids.First()])
```

(Note: the above applies for non empty id sets. The empty sets will simply be added to a separate list during the source iteration pass).

Here is the full method:

```
private static ICollection<List<Log>> GroupIds(List<Log> logs)
{
    var emptyIdsGroup = new List<Log>();
    var idSetById = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
    var mergeSets = new HashSet<HashSet<string>>();
    foreach (var log in logs)
    {
        if (log.Ids.Count == 0)
        {
            emptyIdsGroup.Add(log);
            continue;
        }
        HashSet<string> idSet = null;
        mergeSets.Clear();
        foreach (var id in log.Ids)
        {
            HashSet<string> mergeSet;
            if (idSetById.TryGetValue(id, out mergeSet))
                mergeSets.Add(mergeSet);
            else
            {
                if (idSet == null) idSet = new HashSet<string>();
                idSet.Add(id);
                idSetById.Add(id, idSet);
            }
        }
        foreach (var mergeSet in mergeSets)
        {
            if (idSet == null)
                idSet = mergeSet;
            else
            {
                // Merge the set with less elements into the set with more elements
                HashSet<string> fromSet;
                if (idSet.Count >= mergeSet.Count)
                    fromSet = mergeSet;
                else
                {
                    fromSet = idSet;
                    idSet = mergeSet;
                }
                foreach (var id in fromSet)
                {
                    idSet.Add(id);
                    idSetById[id] = idSet;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var groups = logs
        .Where(log => log.Ids.Count > 0)
        .GroupBy(log => idSetById[log.Ids.First()], (key, group) => group.ToList())
        .ToList();

    if (emptyIdsGroup.Count > 0) groups.Add(emptyIdsGroup);

    return groups;
}
```

Since both building the dictionary and `GroupBy` operations have linear time complexity, the time complexity of the algorithm is also linear. Running it on list containing 25,000 logs should take milliseconds.

**Edit:** The above is good enough, but can further be optimized. The potential costly operation is updating the dictionary when merging sets:

```
foreach (var id in fromSet)
{
    idSet.Add(id);
    idSetById[id] = idSet; // <--
}
```

It can be avoided with the cost of some additional memory by replacing the `HashSet<string>` inside temporary structures with class *holding* a `HashSet<string>` which can set externally:

```
private class IdSet
{
    public HashSet<string> Ids = new HashSet<string>();
}
```

so we can use something like this instead:

```
idSet.Ids.UnionWith(fromSet.Ids); // merge content
fromSet.Ids = idSet.Ids; // and make both objects have the same content
```

This also allows us to perform the merge operation in a single pass and eliminates the need of `mergeSets` variable.

Here is the updated method (note that in contrast with the first implementation we need to use `IdSet.Ids` value as a grouping key rather than `IdSet` object):

```
private static ICollection<List<Log>> GroupIds(List<Log> logs)
{
    var emptyIdsGroup = new List<Log>();
    var idSetById = new Dictionary<string, IdSet>();
    foreach (var log in logs)
    {
        if (log.Ids.Count == 0)
        {
            emptyIdsGroup.Add(log);
            continue;
        }
        IdSet idSet = null;
        foreach (var id in log.Ids)
        {
            IdSet mergeSet;
            if (!idSetById.TryGetValue(id, out mergeSet))
            {
                if (idSet == null) idSet = new IdSet();
                idSet.Ids.Add(id);
                idSetById.Add(id, idSet);
            }
            else if (idSet == null)
                idSet = mergeSet;
            else if (idSet.Ids != mergeSet.Ids)
            {
                // Merge the set with less elements into the set with more elements
                if (idSet.Ids.Count >= mergeSet.Ids.Count)
                {
                    idSet.Ids.UnionWith(mergeSet.Ids);
                    mergeSet.Ids = idSet.Ids;
                }
                else
                {
                    mergeSet.Ids.UnionWith(idSet.Ids);
                    idSet.Ids = mergeSet.Ids;
                    idSet = mergeSet;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var groups = logs
        .Where(log => log.Ids.Count > 0)
        .GroupBy(log => idSetById[log.Ids.First()].Ids, (key, group) => group.ToList())
        .ToList();

    if (emptyIdsGroup.Count > 0) groups.Add(emptyIdsGroup);

    return groups;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, As you said it is processing 30k in milisecond. :)